# Animating border colour yields inconsistent results

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to animate the border color of an element, on a specific event. The following function is called, but the "blinking" border effect either doesn't appear to happen or is barely noticeable:

```
jQ('body').find('a.chosen-single').stop().animate({borderColor: "#3737A2"}, 1)
    .animate({borderColor: "#FFFFFF"}, 250)
    .animate({borderColor: "#3737A2"}, 1)
    .animate({borderColor: "#FFFFFF"}, 250);
```

HTML:

```
<a class="chosen-single chosen-default" tabindex="-1">
    <span>Select An Option</span>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.chosen-container-single .chosen-single {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0 0 0 8px;
  height: 23px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow:none;
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  line-height: 24px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.18s ease-out;
     -moz-transition: all 0.18s ease-out;
       -o-transition: all 0.18s ease-out;
          transition: all 0.18s ease-out;
  padding-left:24px;
}
```

The element should suddenly change border color, fading to white, twice.

If I bump the "1" value up, it begins to become more noticeable, but this isn't quite the visual effect I'm after. What's a better/more reliable way?

EDIT: I'm also using jQuery UI, if that makes answering easier.

Comment: provide css and HTML code

Comment: @Hiral - please see amended.

Comment: it seems to work here [http://jsfiddle.net/vQ3HN/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/vQ3HN/1/)

Comment: Thanks - it looks like the transition rules are interfering. My bad.

Comment: or you can use css animation like this [http://jsfiddle.net/vQ3HN/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/vQ3HN/2/)